# How to make device on Wi-Fi hotspot discoverable to USB tethering connected PC?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, termux, usb-tethering, lan

My goal is to make the device (Quest 2) on `192.168.254.x` (Wi-Fi hotspot) discoverable to my PC on `192.168.96.x` (USB Tethering), because I want to set up ALVR and make my Quest 2 and my PC on different subnets talk to each other.

Right now, I'm testing with **laptop - rooted phone with Termux - PC** configuration. I tried `ip route add 192.168.254.13 via 192.168.96.20` command,
where `192.168.254.13` is my Laptop with Ubuntu and `192.168.96.20` is my PC with Windows 11. My PC does not respond to pings from my laptop, but the laptop does ping the gateway which is `192.168.96.19`, and is getting responses.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but can't figure out what exactly. I don't have much network knowledge and I have a basic Linux understanding, so any answer/tutorial will be appreciated.

I don't need any internet access when on Quest, but I would still want internet on my PC.